# How does this NSMutableArray alloc&init work?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I see a new kind of alloc&init `NSMutableArray` way in one project. It's like this **A**
`NSMutableArray *array = [@[] mutableCopy];` and this works well, and i want to try whether its possible to use **B**`NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray mutableCopy];` it build succeeded, but got this error when used:  `+[NSMutableArray addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x38bedc2c`

Now i want to know how does A work? and why B is wrong? A is better than normal alloc&init?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The first form, `NSMutableArray *array = [@[] mutableCopy];`, is the "smart alec's version" for creating a mutable array, which is actually a mixture of laziness, obfuscation, misconception and inconsideration. It should be done: `NSMutableArray* array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`.

Comment: Ditto. Eloquent. Spot on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, you're first initializing an empty `NSArray` instance; think of `@[]` as equivalent to `[[NSArray alloc] init]`. Therefore you're sending `mutableCopy` to a correct instance, so it works fine.

In the second case, you're sending the message to a class (as opposed to an instance of it), which doesn't make much sense, because the `addObject` message can only be sent to an instance, not the class itself.

Comment: first case is better than normal one? or the same?

Comment: @Chancy, if by normal you mean `[NSMutableArray alloc] init]`, yes, for all practical purposes, they're equivalent.

Comment: (though I'd expect doing `[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` would be slightly faster)

Comment: Faster and not wasting the creation of an NSArray for nothing. So a memory savings. Important if this is done repeatedly and you care about users.

Answer (score 2):

[`mutableCopy`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000050-mutableCopy) is an instance method declared in `NSObject` class. It is called on any instance to create a mutable copy of it.

In first case `@[]` will create an autoreleased `NSArray` instance on which calling `mutableCopy` will create `NSMutableArray` instance.

In second case calling `mutableCopy` on the class is incorrect because it is not meant to be called that way. This will get compiled but will cause exception at runtime. 
Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

`@[]` means an `NSArray` with no object. It returns an `NSArray`, and then its `mutableCopy` is copied to `array`.

`+[NSMutableArray addObject:]` is invalid as `addObject` is an instance method and you are trying to use it as class method.

Even `NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray mutableCopy];` is incorrect!!! As nothing is created, it is not been allocated and inited. If you log the array, it will only print the string `NSMutableArray`. Also you can't use `array` to addObject and other operations.

You should use `NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];`

Comment: or simply: `NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];`

Comment: @JamesWebster: yes you are right, while copy pasting, i did a bad mistake...correcting ...

Answer (score 1):

The first one is lazy typing.
You should avoid it. 
It creates an empty NSArray from the array literal syntax and the creates a mutable copy. 
That's saving a little typing by creating an unnecessary array.

You should just use
[NSMutableArray new] 
Or 
[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]
Or if possible because you know the initial capacity in advance
[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:someNSUIntegerValue]

Anything else above is laziness. 
Only use mutableCopy when you are actually copying some content.